# Webform PHP 8.1 strtolower()

Tags: webform-civicrm

Is D7 and Webform compatible with PHP 8.1? After upgrading to the most recent PHP, I'm hitting an error when loading any webforms with civicrm fields (Civi 5.68.0).

```
Deprecated function: strtolower(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in wf_crm_get_relationship_types() (line 401 of /home/admin/domains/private_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc).
```

Saving the webform node also causes an "unexpected" error.

Answer (score 0):

The D7 version is very old but if you submit a PR to update any deprecations one of the other maintainers or myself would gladly check & merge it.

FYI the message you posted is a deprecation notice, not an error, and shouldn't prevent the module from working.